# Custom Android TextView with a border, and create multiple using for-loop?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, textview

So, I want to create a custom Android TextView with a border INSIDE AN XML FILE, so not programmatically, and create 10 of those using a for-loop. Something like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(//something, //something); 
TextView tv;
String[] data = //Certain data which I'm getting

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest); 
layout.addView(tv); 
}
```

But this doesn't work for me for some reason. So to summarize:

- > Create custom TextView in XML (NOT PROGRAMMATICALLY with Java, but in XML)
- > Create an x amount of this particular TextView
- > Add it to the screen in Java

Can you help me with this?

Comment: You need to use Layout Inflator for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code snippet

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (  ) {
      View listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detaillistitem, _ListLayout, false);
      _ListLayout.addView(listItemView);

      TextView descriptionText = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Text1);
      descriptionText.setText("");

    }
```

R.layout.detaillistitem is item u want to inflate.
_ListLayout is LinearLayout to which you can add above item.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

Create your textview in an external layout file..

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.textview, null);//R.layout.textview is your textview id you want to repeat..
layout.addView(v);
}
```